# Converting NSDictionary initWithObjectAndKeys

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, cllocation

New to using NSDictionary but need some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.

I have an NSDictionary that stores floating point values for coordinates:

Header:

```
@class DetailViewController;
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DestinationData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DestinationSections;

- (void)createDestinations;
```

Main:

```
@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;
@synthesize DestinationData;
@synthesize DestinationSections;

NSMutableArray *museumArray;

self.DestinationSections=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                          ... 
                          ...
                          (@"Museums"), nil];

[museumsArray addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]
                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Museum",@"Name",
                   @"51.5189100",@"Dest Lat",
                   @"-0.1263840",@"Dest Long",
                   nil]];

self.DestinationData=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
museumsArray, nil];
```

I want to be able to return the value from the dictionary and use it with CLLocationCoordinate2D:

In DetailViewController.m:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D destinationLocation;
```

How do I set this value assuming it should be double?

```
destinationLocation.latitude = [[self.detailItem objectForKey:@"Dest Lat"] doubleValue];
destinationLocation.longitude = [[self.detailItem objectForKey:@"Dest Long"] doubleValue];

MapViewAnnotation *destAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"British Museum" andCoordinate:destinationLocation];
[self.detailGoogleMap addAnnotation:destAnnotation];
```

Comment: When I pass my co-ordinates to plot a map annotation, it doesn't plot the annotation in the correct location.

Comment: You have the dictionary inside an array, but it doesn't look like you're accessing it the same way.  You will need to provide more code - show us where `myArray` is stored and show us `detailItem`.

Comment: OK, so how does the dictionary get from `museumsArray` into somewhere accessible from `self.detailItem`?

Comment: sorry, added a bit more info.

Comment: It's used in a table view controller so I pass it like this:     (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.detailViewController.detailItem=[[DestinationData
                                           objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]
                                           objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
}

Comment: Well that looks OK to me - I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Where does it plot it?  Right before the `addAnnotation`, do `NSLog(@"destAnnotation lat=%f, long=%f", destAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, destAnnotation.coordinate.longitude);`

Comment: destAnnotation lat=0.000000, long=0.000000 :(

Comment: could it be related to how i've defined the CLLocationCoordinate2D property:

Comment: @property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

Comment: Next thing I'd NSLog is destinationLocation itself.  Use the same NSLog but with destinationLocation.  If that's ok then the problem might be in the MapViewAnnotation's initWithTitle method.

Comment: Same result Anna: destinationLocation lat=0.000000, long=0.000000

Comment: OK, so you have to keep following the trail backwards until you find out where the data is not getting passed along.  Or follow it forwards from the point you initially set it.  For example: is detailItem nil?  Is detailViewController nil?  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only storing the coordinates as strings because you're not sure how to store a CLLocation2D, there's a better solution: use NSValue to wrap the location.

```
NSValue *locationValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&destinationLocation 
                                        objCType:@encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)];
```

`locationValue` is now a bona fide Objective-C object that you can store in a container like a dictionary or array. Later, when you want to retrieve the location coordinates, do this:

```
CLLocationCoordinates2D destination;
NSValue *locationValue = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"destination"];
[location getValue:&destination];
```

Comment: it looks like there was a problem with one class referencing another before values were set. Caleb- thanks for that. I will give it a try.